# Add player tags to questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Similar to adding ECO tags to questions, should we be able to add player tags to questions.  Not every player should be allowed, but for example, if I only want to see questions that may pertain to Fischer or Kasparov, I can click on the player tag.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe, though guessing there should be a limit, say GMs only.

Comment: Yes, I would not want to allow anyone.

Comment: Okay, makes sense to me, I mean otherwise you might not find get to [watch a robot "attack" Kramnik, and him almost loses his hand.](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/506/is-the-world-chess-blitz-championship-for-robots-going-to-be-broadcast-over-the)